# integrate vert.x and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, vert.x

I have a running app in vert.x. I have many missing features or I just can say missing spring.

How can I integrate vert.x and Spring MVC working on a Tomcat server?

Comment: What features of Spring are you trying to reach? That would be the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Vert.x 3 I would think you would want to use the Vert.x Web capabilities as described [here](http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/index.html) instead of Spring MVC if you want to give Vertx a go. It provides a different approach to developing a web application using the Multi-[Reactor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566653/explanation-of-the-reactor-pattern) than the traditional multi-threaded Servlet model which Spring MVC is based on. With the Servlet model every request runs on its own thread. In Vert.x there is an event loop that is single threaded. All requests are run on the same thread, which requires blocking I/O code to be written in special blocks (see [Core Manual](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/)).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which Vert.x version you are using. 2.x requires a module. like mod-spring-appcontext. In Vert.x 3.x just create a Spring ApplicationContext in your code, typically in the entry point of your application, like your public static void main method. I can't get into more detail. Vert.x questions rarely, if ever, get noticed here.

Comment: Don't know why anyone would downvote my answer. Because it is a correct answer, not the best of the answers here, but a correct answer at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend working with vert.x on a tomcat container as there philosophies are completely different. Tomcat is a servlet container which creates different thread for each incoming call whereas vert.x works on a event-loop. If you are missing spring and will like to use its bean you can integrate it in vert.x environment and run any blocking code in worker verticles. 
You can see an example here : https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/spring-example